# SSRS displaying columns on a matrix to the right

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a table that looks like so:

[image]

Is there any way I can display it like this in SSRS?

```
      1        2       3      4
1    2.091    0.918   0.9   1.718
2    0.647    0.964   0.6   2.264
3    0.804    0.789   0.6   1.9
```

I tried using a matrix but it stops after showing the first column and doesn't expand to show the rest.

Attempt:

[image]

Results:

[image]

**Another attempt:**

[image]

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Your second try looks close, perhaps the column group should be a composite group of id and item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get something similar to the result you're looking for you need to write a query like:

```
select id
,row_number() over(partition by SubscaleNumber  order by SubscaleNumber ) SubscaleNumber 
, item 
 from yourtable
```

[image]

then the matrix should work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Row and Column grouping to get this matrix-style output.

[image]

When you click in your table you should see the brackets for the Row and Column groups. If you don't have a column group, add one.

Go into the properties of each group and make sure they are grouped by the column you want.

Comment: I tried doing this but not sure if I'm doing something wrong here. Added images to display results of my attempt to do this.

Comment: @user3654442 Thanks for the picture. Your raw data is not formatted well. There's no indication that 0.647 for example is related to column 1. This isn't something you can (or should) fix in the report. I would suggest modifying the query to bring back data with the ID's the data is related to.

Answer (score 0):

Start from scratch with a table or matrix.

1. Add a Row group on id
2. Add a Column Group on Item.

Comment: I did try that with a matrix. Just added images to show what happens. The results image is a little cut off but that is the whole result.

Using a table shows all the numbers but not in the format I'm looking to display it in.